# Global planner passes through the wall

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I give a navigation goal to my robot, the global path is just a simple straight between the goal point and my robot current location, even pass through the wall between them. The local planner works well, it is able to navigate to goal point when a short and simple navigation goal is given to it. The following is my move_base launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>   <!--- new added -->
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />

    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/move_base_config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/move_base_config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/move_base_config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="linear_angular"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205102/global-planner-passes-through-the-wall/) by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2015-03-16**:
Is it because I am using carrot_planner? Is there any other planner I can use to solve this problem?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-17**:
Yes. The carrot_planner is (intentionally) very simple, and the behavior you describe is well-documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove the base_global_planner line. The navfn/NavfnROS global planner will then be used.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2015-03-17**:
Thanks! It works!